# Android Http Handler set Token

Tags: android, json, token, httphandler

in my appliaction i use Http Handler to retrive json data and parsing it into a list and all works fine.
Now i must load a seconod json that need a token.
I have generate this token byt http post request, but now i don't know how to set this token in my asynk task
How i can do, this is my code to call json:

```
private class GetUber extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Tariffe.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cacolo tariffa ...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(SERVICE_UBER);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("prices");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("display_name");
                    String costo = c.getString("estimate");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    //JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                   //String tipo = phone.getString("display_name");
                    //String costo = phone.getString("estimate");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("costo", costo);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    uberList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Tariffe.this, uberList,
                R.layout.raw_tariffe, new String[]{"name", "costo"}, new int[]{R.id.tipo, R.id.costo});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: i believe you got some code example from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ if this is the case, you'll have to tweak`HttpHandler` to do POST, or use `HttpURLConnection` class yourself

Comment: Yes i have seen the code write by AndroidHive

Comment: oh, i misread, you already did the POST. Please explain the order of the HTTP requests you need to do, and whether they can be performed concurrently

Comment: I have done a POST and i recive a token. Now il would like to add this token to my code decribe before, but i don't know how

Comment: you can store the token in the current `Activity` and continue your app progress from there. It's more an issue of your app architecture, i think

Comment: I stored the token into a string and now i would like to set it into a http handler call. But http handler not give me the possibility  addHeader("token", TOKEN_STRING);

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add explanation with your code so the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To add a header field in requests made by `HttpHandler` class, you'll need to modify it. You can add this:

```java
public class HttpHandler {

    // ...

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl, String token) {

        // ...

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("token", token);

        // ...
    }
}
```

On a side note, `HttpHandler` is just a wrapper for `HttpURLConnection` Java class, and this wrapper is both limited and limiting. I recommend you to make your own wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

> Add header like below

```
            HashMap<String, String> headers = Constant
                    .getHeaderParameter(cntx);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : headers.entrySet()) {
                httpPost.setHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```